How the soundness / completeness proofs are formalized for new type theories? (with application to automated extension of calculi / proof assistants)
Initial teaser: if we work in the predefined proof assistant/type theory (constructive type theory for Coq, Lean or HOL in the guise of type theory in Isabelle/HOL), then we can state some theorem in the language of this proof assistance and run machine learning algorithms, that search for the proof of this theorem. The proof assistant ("always") can accept or reject of this proof. Even better - if we can formally specify the function (e.g. function that expresses some applied algorithm, Isabelle/HOL has whole book of formalization of applied computing algorithms), then we can ask machine learning to find both the function (resp. algorithm) and the correctness proof or rejection of this newly found algorithm. All this can be done in the unsupervised manner, because proof assistant can check both the syntactic correctness of suggested function (algorithm) and its proof and also the semantic correctness of its proof.
So, if math can be expressed in some proof assistant then it can be automated as well and in the unsupervised manner.
Challenge and Motivation: I have heard, that not all the mathematics can be expressed in the current proof assistants. ∞-category theory (with all the streams of ∞-topoi, ∞-groupoids and HoTT) can be example. Clever people will clarify whether this incapability is fundamental or is just inefficiency (e.g. maybe infinity tower of coherence conditions of ∞-categories can indeed be expressed in the language of the current proof assistants, but it requires infinite amount of text). So - if the new math requires extension of the language of proof assistant and of the proof assistant itself, then this new math can not be readily automated. If we would like to automate new math, then we should automate the evolution of proof assistants as well.
Proposed solution: There is more or less formal language in which the type calculi are presented. This language enables the syntactic extensions and also the expression of usual introduction/elimination/typing/evaluation rules for the new extension and the usual interactions. Examples which can require such extensions can be: higher inductive types, hierarchies of universes, modalities of HoTT. There can be automated mapping from the extensions and rules into the Haskell/Lisp/M/... code that implements the grammar of type calculi and its new rules. Of course, such mapping can be increadibly intricate, but generally - it should be more or less 1:1 or quite controlled and traceable, so - this can be automated (by hand and this automated mapping can belong to the trusted core of the proof assistant, there is no other solution, I guess).
(Automated) supervision It can be easy to generate (more or less random, more or less biased) guess for the extension of the type calculi, then new grammar/new rules mapping to the implementation is automatic (as we assumed). So - the hard question is - how do we check that the generated extension of the type calculi is valuable and sane? Valid? And how we do this automatically (so - no human supervision is required).
The answer comes - as in the real life. Our enhanced proof assistant should come up with 3 things: 1) definition of some semantics; 2) soundness theorem wrt this semantics and the proof of it; 3) completeness theorem wrt this semantics and the proof of it.
So - the machine learning process again generates the guess of the 1-2-3 (semantics and theorems of soundness and completeness and their proofs). And all this can be checked by the extended proof assistant. If it checks, the new extension of type calculi is found whose value can be determined by the breadth of the semantics.
The core question (or, to be more modest - this is the only question that begs for an answer of this question, all the remaining musings about automation are just context and the good answer can avoid these automation issues at all) here is - how do we express and formalize the semantics for the newly suggested extension of the proof calculi? Usually the semantics should be somehow remote from the type calculi? I.e. the semantics should not use the language of the new type calculi. But what other language the semantics should use? And if the semantics can be expressed in that other language, then there is no point in the finding of the new type calculi in the first place? So - my question may be about meta-issues of proof-assistants - how to prove that the calculi on which the proof-assistant is based - are sane and can this sanity be formalized?
So - my question can also involve some requirements and practices how the new type calculi are build, how the semantics for them is constructed and how all this ir formalized?
p.s. I know that mathematicians are not happy about musings, but AMS Bulleting 2024/2, 2024/3 are about automation of math, so - if we continue that courageous adventure, then maybe my question has still some validity?

Clarification: the type calculi can have some grammar, but this grammar is written in some notation, meta-grammar and hence - the new type calculi can have new grammar (extended), that can be written in the same meta-grammar again. So - so - this is implementable formally. Those 2 grammars are just 2 points in the search space.

I'd concur you should narrow that down to something more clear and specific. Just two immediate thoughts: 1) "how do we express and formalize the semantics": isn't that the least of the problems? What does it even mean to guess a semantics?? Isn't that rather the one thing that should be given in order to do anything formally (for something that is not purely formal)? OTOH, 2) just producing theorems, whether systematically or randomly, has the known and immediate issue that you get megatons of totally useless stuff: the problem is how to generate some useful ones, up to some theory...

Thx @JulioDiEgidio for giving hints for the improvement of my question. 1) Of course, FOL and HOL has set semantics and there is little need for anything mode. By my main concern ar HoTT calculi which can admit various semantics, e.g. there can be semantics in the simplicial sets and the semantics in ∞-toposes https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06937 One can invent log of type calculi (or logics) but they are of any value only when they admit some semantics, when they describe something meaningful. And it is quite hard to check this. The crux is - we may beed extended calculi to express ∞-toposes...

... semantics. So, there is some circularity. I don't know, how to resolve this. Most likely, I should try to find whether or not soudness (or even completeness) theorems are formalizes in some proof assistants. This my give clue, how such circularity is resolved.

And, @JulioDiEgidio , regarind your 2). Of course, one can come up with all the consequences of some axioms (or make all the possible sums of integers). Of course, that is useless. But https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-0147-5 is one approach how interestingness is used to come up with valueable theorems only.

I suggest these issues of Bulleting of AMS https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2024-61-02/home.html?active=allissues and https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2024-61-03/home.html?active=allissues They are astounding. But, AFAIU, they are not talking about extending calculus to formalize new math, just formalization in the existing calculi. How, that my clarifications will prevent further down- and close-votes.

Sorry for grammar mistakes, I wanted to reply ASAP and hence some mistakes.

AFAIK, we don't know whether the theory we usually do mathematics in is coherent.  This means that proving the coherence of a theory by exhibiting a model of this theory always implicitly relies on the assumption that there is a model of the theory in which we do this construction, which we don't know whether it is true or not.

Besides this, you mention the example of infinite tower of higher order conditions, that cannot be expressed in eg. HoTT.  A concrete example of this is the definition of (semi-)simplicial types in HoTT, and it is currently unknown whether it is possible or not.  It is possible to express them using very dependent types in Agda, for instance, but yet again, nobody knows whether that is a sound feature of Agda (see this issue).

Also, you mention ML as a way to find stuff without human intervention. However, ML doesn't provide strong theoretical guarantees, that is, so far, ML isn't more capable at deciding a fact P than a very stupid routine that just enumerates all proofs π, and checks whether π : P or π : ¬P.  From a more practical POV, although state of the art ML-powered solvers are very impressive, they are far from currently being efficient enough to just let them run and hope to find in reasonable time an answer "true" or "false", alongside a proof.

@jthulhu for the formal specificatuon of the function (from teaser), GPT or (more likely) graph neural network can invent 1) implementation of the function; 2) proof, that implementation satisfies soecification. Both 1) and 2) are e.g. Isabelle and Isar code. The best thing - there is no need for the human supervision for evaluation of such ML guess - proof assistant gives yes/no answer and possible error trace as a feedback. If the algi generating ML runs as a Reinfircement learning agent, then this agent receives this feedback from proof assistant (there is no need fir human response)

It would help to keep the question focused. The long story about machine learning and proof assistants may be your ulterior motive, but I think it would be wiser to keep it ulterior, if for no other reason to shorten the question and hope people will get to the end of it. Are you asking how semantics of formal systems is expressed formally? Is that your question? It feels like you are asking for some references, but it's hard to tell.

Yes - I am asking "how semantics of formal systems is expressed formally?" Coq implements CIC, but CIC can have and has multiple semantics. And one should formulate and verify soundness/completeness theorems for these semantics. Can this he done in the Coq? And if there is semantic that takes advantage of full expressivenes of CIC, can the soundness/completeness theorems be expressed and verified in Coq? I guess, for CIC it has already be done. But how? And if one can tell this stoye using HoTT/∞-topos semantics (ongoing development), then that would be even better. ...

... but story about Coq/CIC and their semantics can be quite instructive enough as well. I have found https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq#papers and most likely this can give the answer and I can try to create meta-rzk in a similar fashion. jtulhu already told (in its comments) that it can be impossible to do what I am asking. That those foundational issues are always assumed (not proved) in the proof assistants. OK, that may be possible and answer can be along these lines. But then some source, good references about those meta-issues would be warmly welcome. ...

... and, of course, if such meta-proof is not possible (although I am hoping to MetaCoq-like efforts), then how the math community intends to go about automation (continuing the brave efforts of BAMS 2024-2/2024-3) - what would be interesting to know. But - I will - after some time - may open separate question about this. So - answer can avoid this further musings about (unresolved) issues of automation, it is OK.

"And if there is semantic that takes advantage of full expressivenes of CIC..." - and hence - full CIC is needed to express this semantics... - so - how to resolved this circularity, what are the current approaches and are there unresolved problems regarind this? Is math community feeling well about the current approaches regarding this circularity?

Answer can be about any proof assistent. My beloved Coq and rzk are just examples. It may be possible that there other proof assistants with very interesting approaches to these meta-issues.

I'm just going to ignore the ~81% of your post leading to your question:

The core question ... here is - how do we express and formalize the semantics for the newly suggested extension of the proof calculi? Usually the semantics should be somehow remote from the type calculi? I.e. the semantics should not use the language of the new type calculi. But what other language the semantics should use? And if the semantics can be expressed in that other language, then there is no point in the finding of the new type calculi in the first place? So - my question may be about meta-issues of proof-assistants - how to prove that the calculi on which the proof-assistant is based - are sane and can this sanity be formalized?

There are several entangled concerns here:

The proof calculus is "good", in some sense; and
The implementation of a proof assistant is faithful to the proof calculus.

As far as "goodness" is concerned, this can be studied in the broader framework of Meseguer's General Logics and metalogical frameworks. (Heuristically, any system at least as strong as HOL can be a metalogical framework, and thus can prove properties about a deductive system.)
Usually we use a programming language to express and formalize an implementation for a proof calculus of a logic (or operational semantics of a type theory). After all, a programming language is a formal language...
This can lead to concerns like, "What if the programming language is not formally defined? Or its specification is 'bad' [in some sense]?"
Some proof assistants can generate code for the more "formal friendly" programming languages (languages like Standard ML, Haskell, OCaml, and friends). And we can use them to implement a proof assistant *and reason about the implementation.
For example, this has been done in:

Alexander Birch Jensen, John Bruntse Larsen, Anders Schlichtkrull, and Jørgen Villadsen's "Programming and Verifying a Declarative First-Order Prover in Isabelle/HOL". AI Communications Special Issue on Automated Reasoning (2018) 1–20 Eprint

This paper might be worth studying in detail, since it appears to address the concern you have, but for a fairly simple "object of study". (Similar work was done in Fleury's PhD dissertation and Frederik Krogsdal Jacobsen's Master's thesis, both of which are interesting.)
The question might still remain, "But how do we know the generated code is valid and does what we want?"
Well, this concern led to the development of CakeML, which you can read about in the many papers published about the language.
Also a fun effort in this vein is Mario Carneiro's Metamath Zero (see also arXiv:1910.10703 for a summary). It's yak-shaving fun: formalizing the tools needed to formalize the tools needed to formalize a proof assistant.
